# What are some powerful tools for text manipulation and pre-processing in R?

Tags: r, sed, awk

I frequently use Hadley's package `stringr` to clean up messy ecological data (normalizing species names, poorly formatted labels etc). Recently I began learning `sed` and `awk` and am blown away by how powerful those tools are, especially when dealing with numerous data files.

My questions:

1. Are there other powerful text handling packages (outside of `base` functions, and those in `stringr`) that would be useful for data cleaning?
2. Would it be possible to run `sed` commands/scripts from within R? If so, how? Can you give me an example?
3. Has anyone attempted to write a wrapper for `sed` as a R package. If not, would that be a something worth pursuing (A side project for myself or more competent programmers)?

Comment: For #2, seems like invoking `system()` command could do that. I've never used sed or awk, but should work in principle.

Answer (score 5):

First, regarding `sed` and `awk`, I've not generally had a need for them, as they're  particularly old school.  I often write regular expressions in Perl, and achieve the same thing, with somewhat easier readability.  I don't mean to debate the merits of implementation, but when I'm not writing such functions in Perl, I find that `gsub`, `grep`, and related regular expression tools work quite well in R.  Note that these can take `perl = TRUE` as an argument; I prefer Perl regex handling.

Regarding much more serious packages, the [`tm` package](http://tm.r-forge.r-project.org/)  is particularly notable.  For more coverage of natural language processing and text mining resources, check out the [CRAN Task View for NLP](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html).

Also, I think your question title has conflated two concepts.  Tools like sed & awk, regular expressions, tokenization, etc. are important pieces in text manipulation and pre-processing.  Text mining is more statistical, and depends upon the effective pre-processing and quantification of the text data.  Although not mentioned, two subsequent stages of analyses, information retrieval and natural language processing, are research & engineering areas that are more specific in their aims.  If you're primarily interested in text manipulation, then the various tools for applying regular expressions and pre-processing / normalization should suffice.  If you want to do text mining, you'll need to look into the more statistical functions.  For NLP, then tools that do a bit deeper analyses will be necessary.  All are accessible from within R, but the question is how far do you want to go down this rabbit hole?  Wanna swallow the red pill?

Comment: More generally, CRAN's [Task Views](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/) should be the first stop for this kind of question. In this case, [Natural Language Processing](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html).

Comment: @joran You are correct.  Unfortunately, the task view title mentions only NLP, and not text mining.  I also just noticed the Task View doesn't mention `stringr`.  Someone should get `stringr` included in the TV, so that a visitor to its CRAN page will easily find other related packages...

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. I used text mining in the wrong context. I meant text manipulation and data processing. I'll update the title.

Comment: Thanks @joran. If moderators feel that this is too broad and should be closed up, I am ok with it.

Comment: Awww, you don't want to take the red pill?  [Aim high](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194285/dealing-with-messy-dates).

Comment: @Iterator while I agree that Perl is better than sed and awk (lookahead/behind etc) sed and awk are really easy to get started with and do some simple tasks, while Perl takes a little more effort. Its also worth noting that Perl reuses much of the syntax of sed and awk so that investment in them can easily be carried over to Perl, if one should so desire. Sed and awk are also significantly faster, due to the nature of their implementation.

Comment: @richiemorrisroe. You are correct on their merits, but I meant only to give context regarding analogues in R, via a Perl detour.